# Excel 2013 Add a Connector Between Arbitrary Points on Two Different Groups

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working in Excel 2013 to (programmatically) add a straight line connector between the lower right hand corner of a rectangle that is part of a grouped shape with the endpoint of a grouped series of line segments. As it stands, I can't even seem to do this manually on the Excel worksheet that contains these shapes.

Problems include:

1. Only midpoints on the desired rectangle will accept the connector.
2. The grouped series of line segments don't even show a "connection point" for the terminating end of the straight line connector.

Here's a graphic of what I'm trying to do:

[I don't have 10 "reputation points" so I can't seem to post a picture of what I'm trying to do. Not an especially helpful feature! How do I get reputation points in this game?]

I've been able to create and name the two groups and thought it would be a cinch to work with them to add a connector, but that has not been the case.

Here's the code I've been working with:

```
Sub create_new_profile()
    Dim firstRect As Shape
    Dim firstLine As Shape
    Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
    Set s = myDocument.Shapes
'    Set firstRect = s.Range("shpNewGarage")
'    Set firstLine = s.Range("shpProfile")
    Dim Shp As Shape
'    For Each Shp In myDocument.Shapes
    For Each Shp In s
        If Shp.Name = "shpNewGarage" Then
            Set firstRect = Shp
    Else
    End If
    Next Shp
'    For Each Shp In myDocument.Shapes
    For Each Shp In s
        If Shp.Name = "shpProfile" Then
            Set firstLine = Shp
    Else
    End If
    Next Shp
    firstRect.Select 'this works
    firstLine.Select 'this works
'    Set firstRect = s.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 100, 50, 200, 100)
'    Set firstLine = s.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 300, 300, 200, 100)
'    Set firstRect = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("shpNewGarage")
'    Set firstLine = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("shpProfile")
    Dim c As Shape
    Set c = s.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 0, 0, 100, 100)
'    On Error Resume Next
    With c.ConnectorFormat
      **.BeginConnect ConnectedShape:=firstRect, ConnectionSite:=1**
      .EndConnect ConnectedShape:=firstLine, ConnectionSite:=1
'     .BeginConnect ConnectedShape:="shpNewGarage", ConnectionSite:=1
'     .EndConnect ConnectedShape:="shpProfile", ConnectionSite:=1
'     .BeginConnect ConnectedShape:=ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("shpNewGarage"), ConnectionSite:=1
'     .EndConnect ConnectedShape:=ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("shpProfile"), ConnectionSite:=1
     c.RerouteConnections
    End With
End Sub
```

This particular version of the code ends with a runtime error on the line immediately following the line:

With c.ConnectorFormat

Here's the error message:

[I don't have 10 "reputation points" so I can't seem to post a picture of the error message I'm getting. Again, how do I get reputation points?]

Any direction at all to help me accomplish this task programmatically would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for explaining that I can now post images. That should help.

Here are the figures I'm working with:

[image: New garage, existing driveway profile and new profile (red.)]

The rectangle group (firstRect, "shpNewGarage") represents a new garage I plan to build between the existing one and the street. The profile group (firstLine, "shpProfile") represents the profile (side view/elevation) of the existing driveway (the light blue line.) The idea is to attach the new profile (red line) to the lower right corner of the new garage at one end and to the right end of the existing profile (curb) so that as I move the new garage up, down, right and left, the connector representing the new profile will remain attached to these points to show graphically the angle (grade) and length of the new driveway.

Here's the error message I receive when I run the code:

[image: VBA error message.]

This looks like quite a hill to climb, as I am having problems even adding the connector to the desired points manually.

Thanks to all who have read/responded to my issue. Stackoverflow has been a great resource to me in the past, and this is the first time I've ever had to post my own fairly specific problem.

Comment: An Image of the shapes would be helpful (at least for me - I'd like to do it manually). I think your reputation went up to 11 - your question got up-voted. Can you try uploading the image again? I haven't used this functionality before but I think you'll have to ungroup the elements first, to get access to the end points of each element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explained everything very well, and the images you uploaded helped

What your code is doing seems to be correct, but the error is complaining about one of the parameters, and it could be the 2nd one:

.BeginConnect ConnectedShape:=firstRect, **ConnectionSite:=1**

ConnectionSite: "*A connection site on the shape specified by ConnectedShape. Must be an integer between 1 and the integer returned by the ConnectionSiteCount property of the specified shape*"

I think your firstRect has a problem with the first Node: when you initially generate a rectangle it doesn't have connection points in the corners, and I'm not sure about the initial available nodes

A rectangle is a specific class of shape that must first be converted to a (generic) shape class: "*You must apply the AddNodes method to a FreeformBuilder object at least once before you use the ConvertToShape method*", in order to add connection points (nodes) to the corner

Another issue might be caused by groups. I'm not sure if you grouped the objects, but grouping may not allow direct access to connection points

As an exercise, I was able to draw lines between 2 rectangles the way you intended, but my lines are not actually connected to the shapes, so if I move one rectangle the lines will not move with it. Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub create_new_profile()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim shp1 As Shape
    Dim shp2 As Shape

    Dim line1 As Shape
    Dim line2 As Shape

    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws.Shapes

        'AddShape:        Left=10, Top=10, Width=50, Height=30
        Set shp1 = .AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 10, 10, 50, 30)
        Set shp2 = .AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 70, 50, 50, 30)

        'AddConnector:          BeginX=60, BeginY=10, EndX=120, EndY=50
        Set line1 = .AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 60, 10, 120, 50)
        Set line2 = .AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 60, 40, 120, 80)
    End With

    line1.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)   'Color Red
    line2.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End Sub
```

and this is the end result:

[image: connected shapes]

.

If you need the lines to be linked to the rectangles, you'll have to convert the rectangles to shapes, then add corner connection points or nodes (msoEditingCorner), then add connector lines from one corner node of the first rectangle to the other corner node of the second rectangle

One of the ways to (manually) convert to shape, and record your actions to see the generated VBA code and objects used, is by right-clicking the shape and selecting "Edit Points":

[image]

Hope this helps a bit

Comment: This information adds much to my understanding of Shapes and Connectors. I have developed a workaround for what I am doing that basically sidesteps the issues of not being able to connect to rectangle corners ("stock" ones, anyway) and line segments. I created one rectangle around the bottom segment of the bottom "garage" rectangle and one at the "curb" (where the right end of the driveway profile terminates.) I then manually added a red connector between the appropriate sides of the new rectangles, made both invisible, then grouped the left rectangle with the rest of the garage. This worked.

Comment: Great! The end result is what matters, and learning something new along the way :)

Comment: Is there any ways of Editing Point or Adding Connection next to first connection for ex. conn1.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect shap1, 1 .. i have something like this what if i one next connection in point 1 but next to connection 1.