# auto connect/reconnect shapes in excel with vba

Tags: excel, connection, shapes, vba

I have a question. 
I have a lot of shapes in excel it's like flow chart.
Sometimes I need to hide some rows, and flow chart get not correct.
You can see this in pic.

Before hiding rows:
[image]

After hiding rows:
[image]

is there are any macro to write, to do auto connection between shapes, or do reconnect after hiding rows?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837268/excel-2013-add-a-connector-between-arbitrary-points-on-two-different-groups

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shape-rerouteconnections-method-excel

Comment: Did not help ;/